# How do I install MathTime Pro 2 on TexLive (Windows 8)

Tags: fonts, texlive, installing, windows, mtpro

Can someone kindly guide me how to install MathTime Pro 2 on TexLive? I am currently using Windows 8.

Answer (score 4):

I don't own the fonts, so this might be wild guess.  But in general, you should have received a zip(?) file and you have to extract the files into your `texmf-local` directory.  You can locate your `texmf-local` directory at command prompt with:

```
kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFLOCAL
```

The general directory layout of files to extract to is shown below:

```
\texmf-local\fonts\map\dvips\mtp2pro\*.map
\texmf-local\fonts\enc\dvips\mtp2pro\*.enc
\texmf-local\fonts\afm\mtp2pro\*.afm
\texmf-local\fonts\type1\mtp2pro\*.pfb
\texmf-local\fonts\tfm\mtpro2\*.tfm
\texmf-local\tex\latex\mtpro2\*.[sty|fd|cfg]
\texmf-local\doc\fonts\mtpro2\*.[pdf|tex|txt]
```

Next, you have to activate the map-file.  Create the following file (if not already there):

```
\texmf-local\web2c\updmap.cfg
```

and in your favorite editor, add the name(s) of map file(s), e.g.:

```
Map mt­pro2.map
```

Run the commands `mktexlsr` and `updmap-sys` and you should be good to go.

Comment: Your path names work for a Unix-based system. However, the OP has indicated that he/she uses Windows.

Comment: @Mico - Note that I used `backslash` as path separator and not `/`.

Comment: I thought Windows-based path names still start with a "drive letter" (say, "C") and a colon.

Comment: @Mico - I deliberately dropped something like `c:\path\to\texlive\` in my answer since I don't see the added value by duplicating something which would be wrong anyways and reduces the legibility.